# WSO2 Mi 4.2.0 Unresolved Requirement

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

When i am scheduling a task on wso2-micro-integrator ,we are getting class not found exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.EndpointListenerLoader cannot be found by org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer_4.2.0
```

Using Java Version : openjdk version "11.0.22" 2024-01-16 LTS

Below are my error log.

```
[2024-01-23 05:38:24,581]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8317
[2024-01-23 05:38:24,584]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8280
[2024-01-23 05:38:24,585]  INFO {org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.StartupFinalizer} - WSO2 Micro Integrator started in 5.89 seconds
[2024-01-23 05:38:24,590] FATAL {org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} - Failed to initialize ESB due to a fatal error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/inbound/endpoint/EndpointListenerLoader
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:220)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.internal.TasksDSComponent.activate(TasksDSComponent.java:147)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.EndpointListenerLoader cannot be found by org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer_4.2.0
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        ... 38 more

[2024-01-23 05:38:24,624]  INFO {org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.impl.AbstractQuartzTaskManager} - Task scheduled: [ESB_TASK][tskLinkedIn].
[2024-01-23 05:38:24,627] ERROR {Events.Framework} - FrameworkEvent ERROR org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.wso2.micro.integrator.observability [222]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.internal.http.api; version="4.2.0"

        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

[2024-01-23 05:38:24,657]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - {proxy:prxyMrktLinkedIn} To: , MessageID: urn:uuid:1edb3fb1-7688-4988-8dae-c09cb61d436a, Direction: request, log-proxyName = Inside Proxy: LINKEDIN, log-retryCount = 0
```

We are deploying the same car file in both 4.0.0 version and 4.2.0 version. But we are getting this error in 4.2.0 where as its working as expected in 4.0.0

Comment: What is the operating system you are on? Does the server start without the Car app?

Comment: It got fixed once we added these below parameters in micro-integrator.sh.


-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true \
-Djdk.nio.zipfs.allowDotZipEntry=true \